# How to link different parts of documentation together?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Often, when writing an example the author inevitably uses some other features of the language. In typical (good) documentation those mentions are clickable links to the other feature, just like on Wikipedia, though less time-wasting.

Another way is *See also* links. How are those features conveyed by Documentation<sup>BETA</sup>?

Comment: we can use links as they are being used in documentation by users.. 

for eg : 
In Arrays documentation we have reference for reference type

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201607211159424365172